# Oracle TO_DATE is wrongly converting dates after 2020/01/07

Tags: oracle

TO_DATE in Oracle is wrongly converting the following statement:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT 
    to_date('20200108 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D1, 
    to_date('20200107 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D2
FROM dual;
```

Both lines are exactly the same except for the 8 instead of 7.
It doesn't make sense (for me), Oracle converting Tuesday correctly and not Wednesday.
There should not be any DST...

Comment: How can I copy and paste your code so that I can try it on my Oracle instance?

Comment: JNevill edited the question with the code. Thanks

Comment: I noticed it goes back to converting correctly after February 16th. So weird...

Comment: What do you mean by "Oracle converting monday correctly and not tuesday."? Today (monday?) is the 2020-01-06

Comment: I'm unable to replicate over at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Is this your real code? - and the real output?

Comment: Yes, real output.

Comment: I meant Tuesday/Wednesday...

Comment: Works for me on Oracle XE 18c.

Comment: Thanks folks, there must be something related to my timezone (Brazil) or my application driver.

Comment: What happens if you run this in SQLPlus?

Comment: I don't have access to SQLPlus. I just have this screen on my application that connects to the database.

Comment: _I noticed it goes back to converting correctly after February 16th._  February 16, 2019 was the date of the previous DST change in Brazil.  I wonder if your Oracle software hasn't been patched and is getting DST wrong in your time zone.  You could confirm this by changing your SQL\*Developer settings to print date and time by default.  I'll bet that first value is really `07/01/2020 22:00:00`.

Comment: Data type `DATE` does not provide any time zone nor DST information. We would need your real code.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Not sure if that was directed at my comment.  `DATE` may not involve DST logic, but converting it back to a string for SQL\*Developer to print does.

Comment: Can you share what your session  nls_date_format is? e.g. provide the results of this query, `SELECT value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
`

Comment: Tried in livesql and works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved.

The clock on my client's server was configured to use DST and got this error because we were supposed to have DST in Brazil in 2020, but we didn't.

I believe it happened because it's an old Windows Server and might have not updated the DST tables.

Updating the clock on the server solved the issue.

The error itself I believe was generated by the application's driver, and not by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It is the tool you're using, the SQL Developer. It overrides the DB NLS settings with their own.

Go to Tools -> Preferences, then Database -> NLS and check the settings

[image: The tool's NLS settings]